# Error With Ina app Purchases

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have just completed adding in app purchases to my application which i have done using the techotopia ios7 in app purchases tutorial but i am getting this error.  I have looks around and tried some of the solutions given but none have worked.  Has anyone had or can help with this error when setting up in app purchases? my app was running perfectly before

ld: 127 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You need to show more of the error for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: I suspect that you have declared variables in your .m classes and and not your .h header files.  I suspect the new code you have also has the same variable name that you have used in your .m classes.  EG you have myapp.m with a variable BOOL success; and then in your in app purchases class there is another variable called BOOL success; (or something like this) that has the same name. Look at the error you get in the compiler. Search all your files for this variable and put it in your .h file.